# Android Animation when Scroll with images

Tags: android

I am having a problem in creating animation which we have on Box app in android.
I tried everything but unable to rotate the image on next view.

So if you people can provide some guide..... will be very appreciated.

this is the code 
This is the class which I use to swipe the images

public class CustomHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView implements
        OnTouchListener, OnGestureListener, android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

```
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 300;

private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 300;

private static final int SWIPE_PAGE_ON_FACTOR=50;

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private int scrollTo = 0;
private int maxItem = 0;
private int activeItem = 0;
private float prevScrollX = 0;
private boolean start = true;
private int itemWidth = 0;
private float currentScrollX;
private boolean flingDisable = true;

public CustomHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
}

public CustomHorizontalScrollView(Context context, int maxItem,
        int itemWidth) {
    this(context);
    this.maxItem = maxItem;
    this.itemWidth = itemWidth;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        return true;
    }
    Boolean returnValue = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    int x = (int) event.getRawX();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (start) {
            this.prevScrollX = x;
            start = false;
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        start = true;
        this.currentScrollX = x;
        int minFactor = itemWidth/ SWIPE_PAGE_ON_FACTOR;

        if ((this.prevScrollX - this.currentScrollX) > minFactor) {
            if (activeItem < maxItem - 1)
                activeItem = activeItem + 1;

        } else if ((this.currentScrollX - this.prevScrollX) > minFactor) {
            if (activeItem > 0)
                activeItem = activeItem - 1;
        }
        System.out.println("horizontal : " + activeItem);
        scrollTo = activeItem * itemWidth;
        this.smoothScrollTo(scrollTo, 0);
        returnValue = true;
        break;
    }
    return returnValue;
}

public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    if (flingDisable)
        return false;
    boolean returnValue = false;
    float ptx1 = 0, ptx2 = 0;
    if (e1 == null || e2 == null)
        return false;
    ptx1 = e1.getX();
    ptx2 = e2.getX();
    // right to left

    if (ptx1 - ptx2 > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
        if (activeItem < maxItem - 1)
            activeItem = activeItem + 1;

        returnValue = true;

    } else if (ptx2 - ptx1 > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
        if (activeItem > 0)
            activeItem = activeItem - 1;

        returnValue = true;
    }
    scrollTo = activeItem * itemWidth;
    this.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollTo);
    return returnValue;
}

public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}

public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
}

public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {

    return Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX);
}

public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
}

public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onGestureStarted(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onGesture(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onGestureEnded(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onGestureCancelled(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

## }

Main Activity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
 private LinearLayout linearLayout;
 private CustomHorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView;

 int imgid[] = {  R.drawable.logo2, R.drawable.logo3,
            R.drawable.logo4,};

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 int width = MainActivity.this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
 int height = MainActivity.this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
  horizontalScrollView = new CustomHorizontalScrollView(this, 3, width);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layer);
  linearLayout.addView(horizontalScrollView);

  LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(this);
  container.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
  // container.setHeight(height);

  TextView textView = new TextView(this);
  textView.setWidth(width);
 // textView.setHeight(height);
  textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

  textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logo2);
  container.addView(textView);

  textView = new TextView(this);
  textView.setWidth(width);
  textView.setHeight(height);
  textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

  textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logo3);
  container.addView(textView);

  textView = new TextView(this);
  textView.setWidth(width);
  textView.setHeight(height);
  textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


  textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logo4);
  container.addView(textView); 

 // ImageView imageView=new ImageView(this);
    //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo3);
    //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo4);
    //imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
//  imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
//  container.addView(imageView);

    horizontalScrollView.addView(container);

 }

}
```

===========================
the above snippet can swipe the images but I want to rotate the image to 90 degree like vertical to horizontal and also wants shift the same image to next view with proper axis....this is what I want... I am new to android. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: post that "everything" then...

Comment: It would help if you included the code that you're using. Just edit your question and add the code to it.

Comment: please tell me how would I rotate the same image to next view!!
 Like as if I have an image and when I swipe the view to next screen then the image should move to next screen with vertical to horizontal rotation.